# Change color of expand-icon in v-expansion-panel

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

Here is a v-exapansion-panel of Vueitfy.3:

```
> <VExpansionPanels class="py-6 px-16">
>             <VExpansionPanel
> expand-icon="material-symbols:arrow-circle-down-outline-rounded"
> collapse-icon="material-symbols:arrow-circle-up-outline-rounded"
> v-for="faq in faqs"
>                 :key="faq.question"
>                 :title="faq.question"
>                 :text="faq.answer"
> class="expansion-panel mb-2"
>             />
>           </VExpansionPanels>
```

I want the color of exapnd icons when hovering occurs, should have a new one.
how can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple CSS should do it.  Select the expansion panel component then deep select the icon and apply color if hovering:

```css
.v-expansion-panel >>> .v-expansion-panel-title__icon:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

[sandbox example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)